# Converting from Current TimeZone to UTC is incorrect swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, nsdateformatter

I have a function that convert time from my current TimeZone to UTC.

```
static func sendFormattedTimeString(_ string: String?) -> String {
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatterGet.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    if let string = string,
        let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: string) {
        return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
    }
    else {
        print("There was an error decoding the string")
        return ""
    }
}
```

My location is Belarus. It's GMT +3. But in UTC return +1.
Example:
My currentTime: 16:00.
UTC return: 14:00.

What's a problem? Thanks for answers.

Comment: What's your expected result? If it's 16:00 in GMT +3, then it's 14:00 in GMT +1. That looks correct to me.

Comment: UTC - it's GTM 0. This function need to return GTM 0 - 13:00. But it return 14:00

Comment: I tried it for my timezone +5:30 and it worked fine. Did you passed "16:00" or any other string?

Comment: Yes, I passed different strings.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing all above stuff, try using
'TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()', It will return you seconds your job would be converting it to hours and minutes.

Comment: Thank's. I tried this. But i don't understand why is converting incorrect.

Comment: Maybe it could be related to Daylight saving.